# ?e=1 django in custom template

Tags: django

I need to display some aggregated data in my custom template. If i am not getting any params, i want to display the information the last month, othervise for the given period. But when no parameter is given, django tries to redirect me. How can i avoid this redirect?

```
@admin.register(EmployeeStatistics)
class EmployeeStatysticsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/employee_amount_statistics.html'

    list_filter = (
        ('created', DateRangeFilter),
    )

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        params: dict = request.GET

        from_date = params.get('created__range__gte')
        to_date = params.get('created__range__lte')

        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if not params:
            # for the last month
            employee_data = qs.filter(created__date__gte=datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30))\
                .aggregate(
                total_employees=Count('id'),
                new_employees=Coalesce(Sum(Case(When(is_fired=False, then=1), output_field=IntegerField())), Value(0)),
                fired_employees=Coalesce(Sum(Case(When(is_fired=True, then=1), output_field=IntegerField())), Value(0))
            )
        else:
            employee_data = qs.filter(created__date__gte=convert_date(from_date),
                                      created__date__lte=convert_date(to_date))\
                .aggregate(
                total_employees=Count('id'),
                new_employees=Coalesce(Sum(Case(When(is_fired=False, then=1), output_field=IntegerField())), Value(0)),
                fired_employees=Coalesce(Sum(Case(When(is_fired=True, then=1), output_field=IntegerField())), Value(0))
            )
        return employee_data

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        aggregated_data: QuerySet = self.get_queryset(request)
        response = super().changelist_view(
            request,
            extra_context=aggregated_data,
        )
        return response
```